# Yii-PDF Extension Gives Error

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, mpdf, html2pdf

So As My Title Says , I'm Using the [YII_PDF EXTENSION](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/)  , For that I have follow the below steps :

1. Download the Extension from Git. [See](https://github.com/Borales/yii-pdf)
2. Put the edpf extension array in cpnfig/Main.php.
3. Put the extenstions file in Extenstions folder in a directory extensions.
4. Download the mpdf & HTML2PDF and Put the code in Vendors folder.

And When i Run the below code :

```
$html2pdf = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF();
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('analysis_report_pdf', array(), true));
$html2pdf->Output();
```

Than it given me error

> Property "CWebApplication.ePdf" is not defined.

Please Help me where I'm wrong.

Updated :
See What I have added in Main.php:

```
 'ePdf' => array(
            'class'         => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
            'params'        => array(
            'mpdf'     => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.mpdf.*',
                'constants'         => array(
                    '_MPDF_TEMP_PATH' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.runtime'),
                ),
                'class'=>'mpdf', // the literal class filename to be loaded from the vendors folder
                /*'defaultParams'     => array( // More info: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184
                    'mode'              => '', //  This parameter specifies the mode of the new document.
                    'format'            => 'A4', // format A4, A5, ...
                    'default_font_size' => 0, // Sets the default document font size in points (pt)
                    'default_font'      => '', // Sets the default font-family for the new document.
                    'mgl'               => 15, // margin_left. Sets the page margins for the new document.
                    'mgr'               => 15, // margin_right
                    'mgt'               => 16, // margin_top
                    'mgb'               => 16, // margin_bottom
                    'mgh'               => 9, // margin_header
                    'mgf'               => 9, // margin_footer
                    'orientation'       => 'P', // landscape or portrait orientation
                )*/
            ),
            'HTML2PDF' => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.html2pdf.*',
                'classFile'         => 'html2pdf.class.php', // For adding to Yii::$classMap
                /*'defaultParams'     => array( // More info: http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:accueil
                    'orientation' => 'P', // landscape or portrait orientation
                    'format'      => 'A4', // format A4, A5, ...
                    'language'    => 'en', // language: fr, en, it ...
                    'unicode'     => true, // TRUE means clustering the input text IS unicode (default = true)
                    'encoding'    => 'UTF-8', // charset encoding; Default is UTF-8
                    'marges'      => array(5, 5, 5, 8), // margins by default, in order (left, top, right, bottom)
                )*/
            )
        )
    ),
```

Comment: What you write main.php?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you place in extension folder. So, it's should be like that. ext is represent to protected->extensions folder

```
 //For mpdf
 'librarySourcePath' => 'application.ext.mpdf.*', //if your are placed under vendor 'librarySourcePath' => 'application.ext.vendors.mpdf.*',  

  //For HTML2PDF
 'librarySourcePath' => 'application.ext.html2pdf.*',  //or 'librarySourcePath' => 'application.ext.vendor.html2pdf.*',
```

If you put HTML2PF under vendor folder, it's look like that

```
 'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendor.html2pdf.*',
```

Comment: I'm much sure that I'm writing it in application/config/main.php under the components.

Comment: If your putting inside extensions folder for mpdf, you can't rout this way application.vendor.mpdf.*. It's pointing out to protected/vendor. Not extension folder.

Comment: No As you can see in my question , I'm putting the mpdf and Html2pdf in vendors folder.

Comment: Is that inside under 'components'=>array(?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63411/discussion-between-harshal-mahajan-and-k-thiha).

Comment: Did you find solution for it?